# When did Michael start having the visions?

Tags: plot-explanation, underworld

In the movie ***Underworld***, there is a war raging between the **vampires** and the **werewolves**. Selene saves a human from the werewolves (who is Michael) and the story goes.

But Michael is captured by the werewolves and is tied up on a board and talked to  by the werewolf leader. They are talking and Michael then looks at the symbol on the leader and starts having a vision.

**Please someone explain why Michael started having these visions and when he started? If I missed where he started, please tell me, this has gotten me confused.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael is a descendant of one of three brothers - one brother became a werewolf, another became a vampire, but Michael's ancestor remained human. This human link to the original brothers is a fairly major plot point - it is why Lucian is trying to track him down.

His visions begin after being bitten by Lucian. We see later in the movie that memory can be transferred by blood (this is how the vampire leaders transfer knowledge when they transition - and we see Selene do this when she awakens Viktor) - Michael's visions are Lucian's memories.